# How to remove Swarmers from you in ME3

Tags: mass-effect-3

How do you remove swarmers that are already attached to you? They remind me of the [Dead Space swarmers](http://deadspace.wikia.com/wiki/Swarmer). Unlike the Dead Space variety, there isn't a clear visual indicator or action on how to stop them from attacking you.

Comment: I wonder if rolling works? I'll have to try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most any area affect power at point blank will do the trick. Run up to a wall and Incinerate or Singularity. Alternatively have a friend shoot it off of you. Since there's no friendly fire they don't have to worry about hitting you in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Playing as a Vanguard, I always found **Nova** to be quite effective for dealing with the annoying little critters.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of is the Asari's charge-melee, which is an explosion radiating from herself.

Answer (score 0):

They will actually instantly explode once they jump and hit you, so the only way to get rid of them is preventing them from jumping at you in the first place.